# Autoscaling of Google app engine

Tags: cloud, google-app-engine

How does autoscaling of Google App Engine works? Does it add more hardware support without any user intervention?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a quick summary:  https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/scaling#scaling_dynamic_instances

App Engine automatically scales your app up and down as needed. It does not require any configuration.

For comparison, Google Compute Engine also supports autoscaling, but since Google doesn't know what you want to do with your GCE instances, setting that up requires a bit more configuration. See https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/autoscaler/ for more on that.

Comment: Thanks. I also found this great video https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=hcU-cO4P2rA